# Are those sentences both negative or the first one is positive and second one is negative?

Tags: meaning, sentence

For he through Sin's long labyrinth had run,
Nor made atonement when he did amiss...

Does these sentences mean that he did not run from commiting sins nor  made atonement when he did amiss
or
Does it means that he did run from commiting sins but did not made atonement when he did amiss?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us what this is from? (Edit the question).  More context would help to answer.  I'm not sure there is one complete sentence there, but I know there is not more than one.

Comment: This is Byron - "Childe Harold's Departure" - http://www.bartleby.com/205/5.html

Comment: @MaxWilliams- it would not be inappropriate for you to edit that into the question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an archaic use of *nor* as a coordinating conjunction, equivalent to *and not*. You may paraphrase

> For he had run through Sin's long labyrinth, and had not made atonement when he did amiss...

The use was already archaic in Byron's time, but licensed in poetry.